# Can I iterate through a variable argument list without using va_arg function?

Tags: c

I'd like to know if there is a way of iterating through a variable argument lisf without using the va_arg function.
If so, can someone show me an example please?

Comment: No, not portably.  Once upon a time, when all arguments were passed on the stack, you could do a decent job yourself, with some (admittedly hacky) pointer arithmetic.  These days, though, with common arguments always passed in registers, I believe that `<stdarg.h>` is the only way to go.

Comment: It is so implementation dependant and it is not possible in portable way.  Why do not you want to use stdard?

Comment: If you want to know how it is implemented in gcc clone gcc and browse (and the follow the functions and macros) from gcc/builtins.c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, `va_arg` is the only mechanism provided by standard C for iterating over variadic arguments.

There may be other ways on specific implementations (e.g. inspecting stack memory based on how an ABI defines its layout), but they will be non-portable, and there is rarely any good reason to use anything besides `va_arg`.

Comment: I would consider it the comment, not the answer.